# seleccionar el nombre de la fecha mediante sql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

quiero realizar una consulta mediante SQL que me permita ver los registro de todos los meses mediante un parametro que le enviare es el año
como hago para sacar el nombre del mes y luego pasarlo a codigo de laravel. aqui dejo el codigo SQL de la consulta

```
SELECT mes_traslado, SUM(numero_inicial) AS total_anual FROM 
formulario_precebo WHERE año_destete = '2010' GROUP BY mes_traslado;
```

Comment: ¿`mes_traslado` es una columna de tu tabla? ¿de qué tipo es? ¿quieres mostrar el mes en número o en letra? Por favor, da todos los detalles necesarios en tu pregunta, [editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141510/edit), ya que hay cosas que no quedan claras.

Comment: si señor y es un tipo VARCHAR, la Verdad yo no hice la base de datos

Comment: Bien bien... si tienes privilegios para modificar la BD deberías trazar un plan para normalizar los datos, no es tan difícil y te vas a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza y muchos posibles errores. De todos modos, para poder responderte es necesario que indiques cómo están almacenados los datos en esa columna: `YYYYMMDD`  o `DDMMYYYY`, etc.

Comment: los Datos de esa columna solo estan almacenados los meses ya que un compañero mio de la empresa hizo un script en javascript que separa los meses de los años, pero esa columna solo almacena los numeros de los meses y lo que quiero es que me muestre el nombre del mes, me entiendes??

Comment: A ver, para futuras preguntas, cuando plantees un problema indica todos los detalles. Este es mi tercer comentario y todavía no me entero de algo esencial para poder ayudarte: **cómo están almacenados tus datos**. Era lo primero que tenías que haber dicho: *tengo los datos almacenados en una columna del tipo `VARCHAR` y están almacenados así: `1,2,3..., 12...` los meses están almacenados de forma numérica y quiero obtener los meses de los nombres (¿en castellano, en inglés, en alemán...?)*.  ...Eso es lo que he entendido hasta ahora, ¿es correcto?

Comment: correcto amigo mio, y de esa columna que esta en manera numerica, quiero saber que mes es ese numero que esta almacenado y perdona por no formular bien la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, @JuanEstebanYarce agrega toda esa informacion que Cedano pidio correctamente a la pregunta usando el boton [edit]. Y trata de ser mas claro. Ahora, hay varias formas de resolver esto desde el lado del SQL. Mas si tenes acceso a la DB y podes crear tablas por ejemplo. Podrias ademas de todo esto, aclarar si probaste algo, o que cosas no te funcionaron?

Comment: hace poco utilice el codigo de la respuesta de abajo y me sirvio ahora solo me toca como pasarlo a consulta por medio de laravel pero yo me encargo de todas muchas gracias y perdon por no haberla formulado bien;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un uso combinado de `DATE_FORMAT` y de `STR_TO_DATE`.

Para mostrar los nombres de los meses en castellano, puedes usar, antes de la consulta, `lc_time_names`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';

SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado, '%m'), '%M') as mes,
SUM(numero_inicial) AS total_anual 
FROM formulario_precebo WHERE año_destete = '2010' 
GROUP BY mes_traslado;
```

> **NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Dado que los datos están declarados como de un tipo que no es el propio (en este caso un `VARCHAR` cuando debería ser
>   un `DATETIME`). El mantenimiento y funcionamiento de la base de datos
>   se hace cuesta arriba. En muchos casos las consultas darán errores
>   (por ejemplo en cálculos, en columnas que tengan almacenado un mes
>   `13` que no existe, etc). Conviene por tanto que, si tienes
>   privilegios para modificar la base de datos, que traces un plan de
>   normalización, el cual sería muy simple:
>
> 1. Copia de seguridad de la base de datos
> 2. Creación de una nueva columna del tipo `DATETIME` o del tipo `DATE`.
> 3. Actualización de esa nueva columna en base al valor de la columna actual del tipo `VARCHAR`(si no es para almacenar fechas exactas,
>      puedes hacer un `UPDATE` que te cree una fecha que sea el primer día
>      de ese mes.
> 4. Todo parece indicar que el año sería el valor de la columna `año_destete` (por cierto, yo no crearía nombres de columna con `ñ`,
>      acentos ocarácteres especiales).
> 5. Al final tendrías una sola columna en vez de dos, y no tendrías que usar varias funciones para obtener el dato que buscas.

Comment: muchisimias gracias amigo mio, me ayudaste con esto ahora solo me toca a mi como pasarlo a consulta por medio de laravel ;)