# organizar los meses en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy ejecutando una consulta SQL para que me muestre el resultado total por meses seleccionando el año pero cuando se ejecuta me muestra los meses mal organizados
y he utilizado la funcion ORDER BY en DESC Y ASC y no quieren organizar, aqui dejo el codigo SQL y captura de la consulta: me muestra los meses en enero,octubre,noviembre,diciembre,etc y quiero que muestre enero,febrero,marzo,abril..... etc.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS 
mes,AVG(conversion_ajust_fin) AS total FROM formulario_precebo WHERE 
año_destete = 2017 GROUP BY mes_traslado;
```

[image: y esta es la consulta que me muestra al realizar dicha consutla]

Answer (score 1):

Este es uno de los problemas que [te comentaba en la nota de mi anterior respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/141513/29967), **cuando no usas el tipo de datos adecuado**. Te ves obligado a vivir convirtiendo los valores mediante el uso de funciones suplementarias, para obtener los resultados deseados.

En este caso, vas a tener que obtener otra columna convertida al valor numérico del mes (mediante el uso de `%m`) y ordenar por esa columna.

Algo así:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS mes,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado, '%m'), '%m') as mes_numero,   
    AVG(conversion_ajust_fin) AS total 
FROM formulario_precebo 
WHERE año_destete = 2017 
GROUP BY mes_traslado 
ORDER BY mes_numero;
```

Si por algún motivo no te interesa que en los resultados aparezca una columna llamada `mes_numero`, también puedes hacerlo de esta forma (algo fea para mi gusto):

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS mes
    AVG(conversion_ajust_fin) AS total 
FROM formulario_precebo 
WHERE año_destete = 2017 
GROUP BY mes_traslado 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado, '%m'), '%m');
```

Es lo que pasa cuando no se usa un tipo de datos adecuado... :)

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ordenarlo utilizando el alias que declaraste `mes`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS 
mes,AVG(conversion_ajust_fin) AS total FROM formulario_precebo WHERE 
año_destete = 2017 ORDER BY mes ASC;
```